# type to controls on locked workstation?

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I'm using AutoHotKey `Send` command http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm to type to controls. It works fine, but it doesn't work if the workstation is locked.
But I need to type to controls on locked workstation.

If AutoHotKey can not do that I can use any other utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoHotkey scripts still run when the computer is locked, and the [ControlSend](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm) command is able to send keystrokes directly to controls on a window.

Here's a quick test. After running it waits five seconds, opens up notepad, types some text and then beeps through the PC speaker to let you know that it's done. Run the script and lock your computer straight away. Windows key + L works as a shortcut, adjust the value given to the Sleep command on the first line if you need more than five seconds to lock your machine. After the beep unlock your machine and check the Notepad window.

```
Sleep 5000
Run notepad.exe
WinWait Untitled - Notepad
Sleep 300
ControlSend, Edit1, Test typing while locked, Untitled - Notepad
SoundBeep,, 500
```

Notepad was never the active window on my machine after the text was entered, but the text still made it to the window.